# Convert rows to columns oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, pivot

I did not find any suitable previous answers hence posting the question. I need to convert rows to columns. The PIVOT examples all convert the rows to a single  column whereas my requirement is multiple columns. My table looks like this

```
Type     ID
test1    10
test1    20
test1    30
test2    10
test2    40
```

I would like it to be

```
Type       ID        Type      ID
test1      10       test2      10
test1      20       test2      40
test1      30
```

Appreciate your suggestions/inputs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could enumerate rows with `row_number()` and make `pivot`:

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/849c8/1)</sup>

```
select * 
  from (
    select d.*, row_number() over(partition by type order by id) rn from data d)
  pivot (max(type) type, max(id) id for type in ('test1' t1, 'test2' t2))
```

Answer (score -1):

If the 'ID' column is the primarykey you can only have one column as primarykey in the table.

Comment: Het CB,I just called it ID and no its not the primarykey

Comment: ok, you can create four columns like this:
Type|ID|Type_2|_ID_2 or 

Type_1|ID_1|Type_2|_ID_2
Then make a data migration